# jinja2 template expressions

Tags: python, jinja2

Hy, i am very new to web dev and jinja2. i encountered a problem with jinja, when i render template and want to output user name to web page who loged in...well i cant get one. Here is my index.html file with jinja expression in  tag:

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% if user %}

        <h1>Welcome to Flask authentication site, {{ user.name }}!</h1>

    {% else %}

        <h2>Hello, log in or sign up</h2>

    {% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? What code are you using to render the template?

Comment: Please, check [ask].